# Notation of logarithm and its exponent

Tags: notation, logarithms

I am little confused about this notation, $\log^3 n$. Does it mean $(\log n)^3$ or $\log (\log (\log n))$?

Comment: It is impossible to tell. If what you are reading does not tell you which, only context can help (and youhave not provided any context...)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Pardon?

Comment: I mean: it can mean both things, so without further information (context) we cannot help you.

Comment: My guess, without further information, is that it probably means $(\log(n))^3$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Could it mean $\log(\log(\log n))$? I've never seen that usage, and I always thought that $f^n(x)$ meant: $(f(x))^n$, as it does with $\sin(x), \cos(x),$ etc.

Comment: @mikhailcazi, In any context where functional iteration is being discussed, that would be a natural reading. Another possible meaning is $n\log n\log\log n$.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez How $n\log n\log \log n$? Could you elaborate a bit? :)

Comment: @mikhailcazi, in many contexts, expressions like $n\log n\log\log n\log\log\log n$, which are not iterated logarithms but products of iterated logarithms occur with such frequency that naturally people want to write it in a less annoying way. The notation $\log^k n$ is very natural.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Oh okay, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$log^3n$ or $(logn)^3$ means multiplication of $log n$ three times. $log n^3$means logarithm of $n^3$. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 4):

As such, it means nothing, if no explicit definition has been given. It is not a standard notation, unlike notations like $\sin^k x$, which by definition means $(\sin x)^k$. It is a fair guess that $\log^3 x$ is analogously meant to denote $(\log x)^3$, but still just a guess. The superscript could alternatively be a misplaced subscript (base indicator).

Note that the identifier “log”, when used without a subscript, denotes a logarithm with an unspecified base, to be used “when the base does not need to be specified” (ref.: ISO 80000-2, clause 2-12.4), i.e. when base has been specified earlier or the text discusses properties that the logarithm functions have independently of base. It is inappropriate, and causes real risks of misunderstanding, to use “log” instead of “lg” (base 10 logarithm) or “ln” (natural logarithm) or “lb” (base 2 logarithm), expecting “log” as such to indicate a specific base.